# $scope.$watch not catching the value modified by directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-watch, angularjs-digest

My directive give focus to my span and assigns **boolean** value i.e, focusToSpan to true whenever I press **shifttab**,however, this change is not reflected in my **controller** and in the **template**. I even checked with $scope.$watch on focusToSpan variable as below

**Directive**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("my.page").directive('getFocusToSpan', function() {
        return {
            link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                elem.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
                    if (event.which === 16) {
                        $('.iconclass').attr("tabIndex", -1).focus();
                        scope.focusToSpan = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        };

    });

})();
```

**Controller**

```
     $scope.$watch('focusToSpan', function(newValue) {
     if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {

     alert(newValue);
     }
     });
```

which is not getting called.May I know how the change made to a  controller variable in the directive will be reflected in the controller and in the template.
Thanks,
Balaji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside angular context you manipulate scope/binding that doesn't get updated. For making binding updated you need to run digest cycle to update all scope level bindings.

Here in your case you are updating angular `scope` variable from custom event, so you need to run digest cycle manually by doing `$apply()` method on scope

**Code**

```
elem.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.which === 16) {
       $('.iconclass').attr("tabIndex", -1).focus();
       scope.focusToSpan = true;
       scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pankaj, will try and let you know

Comment: @balaji Glad to hear that..Cheers & Thanks :)

Comment: I suggest using `evalAsync()` instead, because it will only trigger a new digest cycle if needed (i.e. if one is not already in progress).

Comment: @plamut its basically you need to run digest after an Manuel event..likewise there are many ways to do the same..$evalAsync , $timeout & $apply()

Comment: Yes, there are many way, but some of them are slightly better. ;) With `$evalAsync()`, the change is propagated later in the same digest cycle if one is already in progress, while `$apply()` triggers a new cycle (or raises an error if one is already in progress).

Comment: @plamut I don't think so here use its required...but would be good if we have it..Thanks for your comments..